# Embed and execute native code from memory

Tags: windows, winapi, native-code

I want to do these two things with my application (Windows only):

1. Allow user to insert (with a tool) a native code into my application before starting it.
2. Run this user-inserted code straight from memory during runtime.

Ideally, it would have to be easy for user to specify this code.

I have two ideas how to do this that I'm considering right now:

1. User would embed a native dll into application's resources. Application would load this dll straight from memory using techniques from [this](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) article.
2. Somehow copy assembly code of .dll method specified by user into my application resources, and execute this code from heap as described in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/21/dynamicbase-and-nxcompat.aspx) article.

Are there any better options to do this? If not, any thoughts on what might cause problems in those solutions?

**EDIT**

I specifically do not want to use `LoadLibrary*` calls as they require dll file to be already on hard drive which I'm trying to avoid. I'm also trying to make dissasembling harder.

**EDIT**

Some more details:
Application code is under my control and is native. I simply want to provide user with a way to embed his own customized functions after my application is compiled and deployed.

User code can have arbitrary restrictions placed on it by me, it is not a problem.

Comment: The normal and straight forward way would be to dynamically load a dll using LoadLibrary() from the file system, and call a well known function in that dll. Is that not feasible

Comment: I would like to avoid calling `LoadLibrary` as it requires .dll file already on hdd, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What's wrong with [`LoadLibraryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms684179.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683212.aspx)? Also, what do you mean by *"run [...] straight from memory"*? As opposed to running from? Problems with your proposed solutions: anti malware and virus protection software will run haywire.

Comment: If you want to avoid a file staying on the HDD when your app terminates you can create it with [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) creation disposition.

Comment: @IInspectable That's true, but `LoadLibrary` call can be very easily intercepted while cracking (by even most inexperienced).

Comment: You should probably specify your requirements in more detail then. What are you essentially trying to achieve? Is the tool under your control? Is your application a native application or .NET or WinRT?

Comment: Can you say "Used mostly for purposes causing it to be quarantined or deleted by all antivirus/malware detection software" or "Allows you to be easily banned by any and all responsible corporate IT departments"? It will read really well in your product literature.

Comment: You want to allow third parties to statically link code into your application.  So give them your object files and a linker.  You can wrap this up in a tool to make it easy for the third parties if you like.

Comment: @KenWhite That's pretty harsh. Why would it be different from upx packers or creating .dll on disk and then loading it? I do things like that in .NET routinely and it never was a concern.

Comment: If you are worried about `LoadLibrary` being intercepted you should be equally concerned about [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898.aspx) being intercepted. And all of a sudden your carefully crafted scheme falls apart.

Comment: Creating a DLL on disk results in the file being scanned. AV software that detects execution of code that suddenly appears from data areas in memory will (and should) catch what you're trying to do as potentially malevolent behavior. Your design allows execution of what's basically intended to be data. .NET does something totally different (runtime compilation that's easily detectable and scannable, using documented functionality of the framework); your app is basically allowing user-supplied data to execute at will with none of those features that AV software can recognize.

Comment: (continued) Also, doing so in .NET is totally different. The framework itself protects the user from most malicious behavior by a software author; it prevents most of the things that malware would attempt by design. Native code has none of that protection built in. Apples vs. oranges for comparison between native code and .NET code.

Comment: @Ken White I can invoke any native code from those memory loaded .dll's with pinvoke.

Comment: In other words, a .dll loaded from disk that has been scanned before. Again, this is different. You're using executable code and execute it. You're not taking a data segment and redeclare it as executable code. That's essentially what @Ken is saying.

Comment: @arx I didn't really consider AV problems with this design. It seems your solution is most elegant way to do this.

Comment: @IInspectable You might be right, but there is still software that generates and executes native code on the fly (packers/emulators/JITers/etc..).

Comment: Packers don't "generate code on the fly"; they decompress code that's already there (and that was compressed by known algorithms that can be recognized in the exe itself). JITers do the same (as I mentioned with .NET previously). Emulators aren't the same thing at all; they're *emulators*, that can be scanned in advance and run something in a protected environment. You're again comparing apples and oranges. You're asking about native code being produced from a data area of memory and executed as native code without the user's knowledge, which is what AV software is designed to prevent. :-)

Comment: :-) This is veering off into a discussion. I'll give you the last word, and then I'll go back and remove my previous comments to get rid of the clutter.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not asking at all to execute code from data area. I'm simply asking for easiest and most elegant way to change some code in existing native application. I could simply modify the executable and change assembly for a function, but it would be a lot of work to do it in a portable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim is to allow third parties to statically link code into a native application.

The obvious way to do this is to supply the third parties with the application's object files and a linker.  This could be wrapped up in a tool to make it easy to use.

As ever, the devil is in the detail.  In addition to object files, applications contain manifests, resources, etc.  You need to find a linker that you are entitled to distribute.  You need to use a compiler that is compatible with said linker.  And so on.  But this is certainly feasible, and likely to be more reliable than trying to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your option 2 is pretty much intractable in my view. For small amounts of self-contained code it's viable. For any serious amount of code you cannot realistically hope for success without re-inventing the wheel that is your option 1. 
For example, real code is going to link to Win32 functions, and how are you going to resolve those? You'd have to invent something just like a PE import table. So, why do so when DLLs already exist. If you invented your own PE-like file format for this code, how would anyone generate it? All the standard tools are in the business of making PE format DLLs.

As for option 1, loading a DLL from memory is not supported. So you have to do all the work that the loader would do for you if it were loading from file. So, if you want to load a DLL that is not present on the disk, then option 1 is your only choice.

Any half competent hacker will readily pull the DLL from the executing process though so don't kid yourself that running DLLs from memory will somehow protect your code from inspection.

Answer (score 0):

This is something called "application virtualization", there are 3rd party tools for that, [check them on google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=virtualization%20sdk&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&channel=suggest&fp=10e8492a16600ada&psj=1&q=application%20virtualization%20for%20developer%20tools).

In a simple case, you may just load "DLL" into memory, apply relocs, setup imports and call entry point.